# Laravel 4 - Update Div Using Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 and am trying to update a (#articles) div with the new articles that are retrieved from an ajax request. When I inspect the page and view the Network section, I can see the POST requests being fired off and it's not showing any errors (eg, articles appear to be returned). However, unfortunately, the `#articles` div is not being updated with the new information. Yet, if I do a browser refresh, the new articles are displayed.

Routes.php

```
Route::any("/dashboard/latest_sa", [
    "as"    => "dashboard/latest_sa",
    "uses"  => "DashboardController@latest_sa"
]);
```

controllers/DashboardController.php

```
Class DashboardController extends \BaseController
{
...
   protected function latest_sa()
    {
      if( Request::ajax() )
      {
        // called via ajax
        $articles = Articles::orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return json_decode($articles);
      } 
      else 
      {
        // fresh page load
        $articles = Articles::orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return $articles;
      }
  }
...
}
```

app/views/dashboard/default.blade.php

```
...

@section("content")

// defined in /public/js/main.js
<script type="text/javascript">
    callServer();
</script>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

    <h4>Latest Articles</h4>

    <div class="articles">
        <ul>
        @foreach ($articles as $article)
            <li>
                <img src="{{ $article->user_image }}" alt="{{ $article->article_title }}" />
                <a href="{{ $article->article_link }}">{{ $article->article_title }}</a>
                <div class="details">
                    <span class="author">{{ $article->author_name }}</span>
                    <span class="created">{{ Helpers::time_ago($article->published_at) }}</span>
                    <span class="symbol"><a href ="{{ $article->symbol_link }}">{{ $article->symbol_title }}</a></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{ $articles->links() }}
</div>

...
```

/public/js/main.js

```
function callServer()
{
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dashboard/latest_sa",
            success:function(articles)
            {
                $(".articles").html(articles);
            }
        });
    },5000);
}
```

JS is hardly my strong suit, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

And, for clarity sake, the reason why I'm trying to update all of the articles in the div is so that the `Helpers::time_ago` method also gets called, instead of just fetching the new articles. This way, it properly shows how long ago the article was published (eg, less than a minute ago, a minute ago, a hour ago, a day ago, etc) without refreshing the page. Essentially, I'm trying to kill two birds with one stone; update the div with the most recent articles, and update the remaining article's `published_at` attribute using my Helpers::time_ago method. If there is a more effective / efficient way of doing this, feel free to correct me. This seems rather crude, but since it's only for personal use and will never be used for commercial purposes, it suits my needs (not that that excuses bad code).

Nonetheless, from my fairly basic understanding, the JS should be doing the following steps:

1) Fire a POST request off to the `/dashboard/latest_sa` route

2) Execute the `DashboardController@latest_sa` action

3) Return a DB collection of all `$articles` ordered by the latest published date, and paginated

4) Pass the `$articles` collection back to the JS `success` attribute (as `articles`)

5) Fire the anonymous function, with the `articles` collection as an argument

6) Update the corresponding inner HTML with the results from the `articles` collection

The logic sounds right, so I'm pretty sure this is going to be a human error (98% of the time it is, after all. lol). Hopefully, someone here will be able to see the (probably glaring) problem in the logic and point me in the right direction.

In the meantime, I'm going to keep toying around with it.

I look forward to your thoughts, ideas, and suggestions. TIA.

---

### EDIT:

Well, I found one of the problems; the articles div is a class, and in the JS I'm referring to it as an id. I fixed that, and now after the timeInterval, the article's div is "updated" but no results are being displayed (none, zippo, nadda).

Yet, if I directly access the `/dashboard/latest_sa` URI I get the valid JSON response that I'm expecting. So, albeit I am closer, I am still missing something.

---

### EDIT 2:

Okay, in the controller, I made some changes which can be seen above, where I am now doing a json_decode on the $articles, before returning them to be passed into the view. With that in place, the articles are showing back up again after the timeInterval has elapsed, however, the new articles and the `published_at` for the existing articles are not being updated. After reviewing Inspect -> Network, it shows that the server is responding with a 500 Internal Server Error from the ajax POST request.

Hrm... Seems like I'm going in circles. Sounds like a good time to take a break and go for a walk. ;)

---

### EDIT 3:

Well, I modified my Helpers class and added in the following method to check if the `$article` is a json object.

```
public static function isJson($string)
{
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

app/views/dashboard/index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <?php
        if( Helpers::isJson($article) )
        {
            $article = json_decode($article);
            // dd($article) // when uncommented it returns a valid PHP object 
        }
    ?>
    <!-- Iterate over the article object and output the data as shown above... -->
@endforeach
```

As you can see, (for the time being) inside of my view's `foreach($articles as $article)`, I run Helpers::isJson($article) as a test and decode the object if it is json. This has enabled me to get passed the 500 Internal Server Error message, populate the articles div with the results on the initial load, and after the ajax POST request is fired off, I'm getting back a server response of `200 OK` according to Inspect -> Network. However, after it updates the div, it doesn't show any articles.

Around, and around I go... I think it's time I take that break I keep murmuring about. ;)

Any thoughts, suggestions and / or ideas are greatly welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Well, after 'Edit 2' I am now receiving an Internal Server Error per the Inspect -> Network -> Post request. So, time to dig into those logs. I'll update the question with what I find.

Comment: Okay, so after changing the controller to do a json_decode on the $articles collection, and passing that to the `success` attribute to be used by the anonymous function, I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error per the logs. So, either 1) Something is not configured correctly, or 2) I'm a bit daft.

Comment: I updated the question with a section 'Edit 3' which describes the current situation. Hopefully this helps narrow the underlying problem down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should know that, when you return a collection from the controller/route, the response automatically turns in to a `json` response so, you don't need to use `json_decode()` and it won't work, instead, you may try something like this (from your controller for ajax):

```
$articles = Articles::orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
return View::make('defaultAjax')->with('articles', $articles);
```

Since building the `HTML` in the client side using the `json` data received from server side would be tough for you so, you may return `HTML` from the server with the generated view instead of `json`, so you may try something like this in your `success` handler:

```
success:function(articles) {
    $(".articles").html(articles);
}
```

Now create a view for `ajax` response without extending the template like this:

```
//defaultAjax.blade.php used in the controller for ajax response

<ul>
    @foreach ($articles as $article)
        <li>
            <img src="{{ $article->user_image }}" alt="{{ $article->article_title }}" />
            <a href="{{ $article->article_link }}">{{ $article->article_title }}</a>
            <div class="details">
                <span class="author">{{ $article->author_name }}</span>
                <span class="created">{{ Helpers::time_ago($article->published_at) }}</span>
                <span class="symbol"><a href ="{{ $article->symbol_link }}">{{ $article->symbol_title }}</a></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
{{ $articles->links() }}
```

Notice, there is no `@extendds()` or `@section()`, just plain partial view, so it'll be rendered without the template and you can insert the `ul` inside the `.articles` div. That's it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight! Actually, I only got this far thanks to an answer you posted on another SO article, so thank you very much for being an active contributor to SO. With that being said, I'm gonna go make this happen. Thank you very much for enlightening me.

Comment: Really glad to know that it helped you and you are always welcome my friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#articles").html(articles); ->> $(".articles").html(articles);
```

Comment: I was just updating my answer with that being one of the corrections. Good catch, nonetheless. And, thank you for the response. :D  I'd be love to hear any further insights though as I'm closer, but it's still not working as expected...